# VS code debug console input

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug the following try C++ program with VS code on MacOS. It requires input from the user. It's just something that takes two numbers as input and returns a list of numbers as output. This is my launch.json

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
"name": "(lldb) Launch",
"type": "cppdbg",
"request": "launch",
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/hello",
"args": [],
"stopAtEntry": false,
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
"environment": [],
"externalConsole": true,
"MIMode": "lldb"
}
]
}
```

When I press F5 is that an external terminal window is indeed started but it doesn't execute the output file "hello", it just shows the regular prompt on my home folder ~. If I simply run the file normally everything runs as normal.
I will post the exact code I'm trying to debug as an example, since it's simple enough.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Calculator
{
private:
    /* data */
public:
    Calculator(/* args */) {}
    ~Calculator() {}
    void PrimeGenerator(int, int);
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Please enter two numbers: " << endl;
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    Calculator c;
    c.PrimeGenerator(x,y);

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

void Calculator::PrimeGenerator(int x, int y)
{
    for (int i = x; i < y; i++)
    {
        bool prime = true;
        for (int j = 2; j * j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j != 0)
            {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (prime==true) {
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than describe your code, please post as text, an [mcve].  Images don't paste into IDEs, and links to sites break down or are blocked by firewalls.

Comment: Done. That hello cpp with its compiled output and the launch.json should be reproducible.

Comment: To pause the code at the end, I usually use `std::cout << "Paused. Press ENTER to continue"; std::cin.ignore(1000000, '\n');`  This waits until an ENTER is pressed or the given number of characters have been input.

Comment: at this link there is a video where the exact code I had, on VS code, on a MacOS, works just fine <https://youtu.be/-erXR6k9TeE?t=1280>

Comment: I tried to follow your advice but it didn't change much. The external terminal opens but it is just a prompt in my home and it's not running my program.

Answer (score 7):

It seems there's no problem with the code itself.

Do you have a hard requirement for the external console? If not, can run the application manually in the terminal and than attach:

```
{
    "name": "(lldb) Attach",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "attach",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/hello",
    "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
    "MIMode": "lldb",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ]
}
```

After you hit the run button, VSCode will ask you for the pid:
[image]

Now, will be able to debug:
[image]

Comment: I don't necessarily need the external console, but I certainly need to input x and y. I need to make that happen somehow. You suggestions lead to the error: "Property console is not allowed"

Comment: I didn't realized that the `console` property is not available for every language. So I tried to reproduce the situation (on Linux, and got a similar problem as you) and found a working way. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Once VS code asks for the pid and I type it in, the process in my console outputs that it's getting PAUSED, but it actually quits.

Comment: That's wired. Because I do not have a Mac here (only Linux and Win), I cannot go deeper here. The only thing I can confirm, that it's working on Debian Linux (and only via the attach variant, without that I got a similar problem as you).

Comment: Just to clarify, the only thing that should be on my launch.json is the snippet you posted and I should just start my hello on an external terminal window, but not input the numbers and then attach. After that I should be able to input the numbers and see the variables in the debugger, or at least you do. Right?

Comment: That's correct. I updated my answer with a screenshot.

Comment: But I think I've found out the reason why it's crashing: Whenever I resize the window during the number prompt, several control chars are sent to the stream so the read number is total garbage and the int-conversion will fail.

Comment: I noticed that you input the numbers and press enter and yet you have no output, that's weird. Well, it's still not working so I cannot fully accept the answer, but I will upvote you for working hard to try :D. Why do you resize the window?

Comment: What bugs me is that it seems to work seamlessly for some people
https://youtu.be/-erXR6k9TeE?t=1277

Comment: Why do you think I have no output? Check where the breakpoints are set. Of course, when continuing, with valid numbers, some numbers are printed (from the prime generator).

Comment: True, apologies, I didn't check your breakpoints. What shell do you use? Bash?zsh?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212085/discussion-between-arakis-and-karl).